# Orderby on multiple columns using typeorm

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, sql-order-by, typeorm

In my application, I am using `MySQL` and `typeorm` and want to do `orderBy` using multiple columns. I searched so many places for it but did not get any solution.

Example:
I have two columns in a table user and respective User Entity

```
________________________________________
| id | name | createDate | createdTime |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | Sai  | 2020-12-12 | 12:20:30    |
........................................
| 2  | Ravi | 2020-12-13 | 13:20:30    |
........................................
```

Here, I want to orderBy createdDate and CreateTime both using `typeorm` something like below.

```
CM.getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select(["name", "id"])
      .orderBy('user.createdDate', 'ASC')
      .AndOrderBy('user.createdTime', 'ASC')
```

Please help me solve this.

Thank you...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/fde9f0772eef69836ff4d85816cfe4fd6f7028b4/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts#L894):

> ```
> /**
>  * Adds ORDER BY condition in the query builder.
>  */
> addOrderBy(sort: string, order?: "ASC" | "DESC", nulls?: "NULLS FIRST" | "NULLS LAST"): this;
> ```

Just replace `AndOrderBy` to `addOrderBy`:

```
CM.getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select(["name", "id"])
      .orderBy('user.createdDate', 'ASC')
      .addOrderBy('user.createdTime', 'ASC')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a shorthand version if you do not want to user Query Builder.

```
    const users = await User.find({
      where: { userId },
      order: { createdAt: "ASC", createdTime: "ASC" },
     });
```

It will sort based on the first column createdAt first, then the second. column createdTime.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.